# SQL GROUP CORRELATED QUERY

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, subquery, correlated-subquery

After failing to do so using window functions I have created a analytic summary view of my data by using a lot of correlated queries. I have a bad feeling about the future performance of this view, I am sure there is a better way to do this and I would love to learn how. I have read that the same is achievable using a JOIN, but because I have several different WHERE conditions on my subqueries I can't seem to get my head around it. The code for the view is below:

```
SELECT colG1, colG2, colG3,

-- GET MIN AND MAX
MIN(colA) AS MinA, 
MAX(colA) AS MaxA,

-- GET TOP VALUE
(SELECT TOP (1) colA
FROM myTable
WHERE colG1 = t1.colG1
    AND colG2 = t1.colG2
    AND colG3 = t1.colG3
ORDER BY Date DESC) 
AS TopA, 

MIN(colB) AS WorstB,

-- GET COUNT OF LESS-THAN 0
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE (colA < 0) 
    AND colG1 = t1.colG1
    AND colG2 = t1.colG2
    AND colG3 = t1.colG3) 
AS LosingCount,

-- GET COUNT OF GREATER-THAN 0
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
WHERE (colA >= 0) 
    AND colG1 = t1.colG1
    AND colG2 = t1.colG2
    AND colG3 = t1.colG3) 
AS WinningCount

FROM myTable AS t1
GROUP BY colG1, colG2, colG3
```

I can't help getting confused between the GROUP and WHERE and a potential JOIN. Apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you kindly.

Comment: You can do the less / greater than calculation using case, for example sum(case when (colA < 0) then 1 else 0 end) as LosingCount

Comment: Thanks! That removes 2/3 of the subqueries :)